# File update keeps saving old information instead of updated information

Tags: java

In my program I have a display button. As soon as I click it the information is displayed and saved into file.

This is my code so far:

```
public void LoadFromFile(){

    FileWriter writer;

    try{
       writer = new FileWriter(fileName1, true);
       writer.write("Manager: "+Manager + System.getProperty("line separator "));
       writer.write("\nSortCode: "+SortCode + System.getProperty("line separator "));
       writer.write("\nWorkingHours: "+WorkingHours + System.getProperty("line separator "));
       writer.write("\nHouse No: "+LoadFromFile.getHouse_no()+System.getProperty("line separato " ));
       writer.write("\nHouse Name: "+LoadFromFile.getHouseName()+System.getProperty("line separator "));
       writer.write("\nStreet: "+LoadFromFile.getStreet()+System.getProperty("line separator "));
       writer.write("\nTown: "+LoadFromFile.getTown()+System.getProperty("line separator "));
       writer.write("\nCountry: "+LoadFromFile.getCountry()+System.getProperty("line separator "));
       writer.flush();
       writer.close();
       writer = null;


    }catch(IOException ioe){

    }


}
```

In my program I have a save button so when I edit the information and save it, it will change and display the new information.

However it just copies the old information into the file rather the new.

```
public void SaveToFile(){
       FileWriter writer;

        try{
           writer = new FileWriter(fileName1, true);
           writer.write("Manager: "+Manager + System.getProperty("line separator"));
           writer.write("\nSortCode: "+SortCode + System.getProperty("line separator"));
           writer.write("\nWorkingHours: "+WorkingHours + System.getProperty("line separator"));
           writer.write("\nHouse No: "+SaveToFile.getHouse_no()+System.getProperty("line separator"));
           writer.write("\nHouse Name: "+SaveToFile.getHouseName()+System.getProperty("line separator"));
           writer.write("\nStreet: "+SaveToFile.getStreet()+System.getProperty("line separator"));
           writer.write("\nTown: "+SaveToFile.getTown()+System.getProperty("line separator"));
           writer.write("\nCountry: "+SaveToFile.getCountry()+System.getProperty("line separator"));
           writer.flush();
           writer.close();
           writer = null;


        }catch(IOException ioe){

       }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that your code is throwing an exception and never completing the `try` block. Instead of ignoring your exceptions, you could call `ioe.printStackTrace();`. This will print any IOExceptions that occur, and you can use this information to solve the problem.

Comment: Why do you write the file in a method called `LoadFromFile`?

Comment: I am storing the information in a file, then to display it, it then loads from file but I want anything that I change in the display to be updated in the file because thats where it loads from